# Dockerized PGAdmin Mapped volume + COPY not working

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-volume

I have a scenario where a certain data set comes from a CSV and I need to allow a non-dev to hit PG Admin and update this data set. I want to be able to put this CSV in a mapped folder from the host system and then use the PG Admin GUI to run a `COPY` command. So far PG Admin is telling me:

*ERROR:  could not open file "/var/lib/pgadmin/data-files/some_data.csv" for reading: No such file or directory*

Here are my steps so far, along with a sanity check inspect:

```
docker volume create --name=data-files

docker run -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL="pgadmin@example.com" -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=some_pass -v data-files:/var/lib/pgadmin/data-files -d -p 5050:80 --name pgadmin dpage/pgadmin4

docker volume inspect data-files  --format '{{.Mountpoint}}'
/app/docker/volumes/data-files/_data

docker cp ./updated-data.csv pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin/data-files
```

And, now I think that PG Admin could see the `updated-data.csv`, so I try COPY, which I know works locally on my dev system where PG Admin is on baremetal:

```
COPY foo.bar(
    ...
)
FROM '/var/lib/pgadmin/data-files/updated-data.csv'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER
ENCODING 'windows-1252';
```

Is there any glaring mistake here? When I do docker cp there's no feedback to stdout. No error, no mention of success or a hash or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you thought the file should be inside the pgadmin container however the file you are going to copy must be **inside the postgres container** so the query you run will find the file. I suggest you copy the file to postgres container :

```
docker cp <path_from_your_local>/file.csv <postgres_container_name>:/file.csv
```

Then in the query tool from your pgadmin you can copy without problems !

I hope this help to others came here...

Comment: Seems you are probably correct, but I can't test it conveniently. I've long moved from that project, but I hope your answer will help others. To others, if this works please let me know I should accept this answer?

Comment: One way to test it is to run both containers, postgres and pgadmin, then in postgres create a table with the same columns from the csv file. Finally execute the command to copy the csv in the postgres container and from your browser using pgadmin execute the query but with the difference that your path to the file is the path that is inside the postgres container. For more detailed information you can read the following post: https://dev.to/adron/getting-copy-for-bulk-csv-working-on-a-container-running-postgresql-3kk9